Method to convert Windows time zones to IANA time zone database in PowerShell
I wasn't able to find a good method for converting windows time zones to the IANA format I needed. This method isn't perfect but it gets the job done for my purposes.
First you need to get the windowsZones.xml file from:
https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml
The following PowerShell script converts the XML into the body of the switch statement used in the lookup script. This is based on another script I found here on StackOverflow.
# https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml

# Download the xml file.
[Xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path "windowsZones.xml"

# Parse the fields we want from the XML.
$mappings1 = $xml.supplementalData.windowsZones.mapTimezones.mapZone | select Type,Other 

# Extrapolate extra rows for entries that contain more than one IANA name seperated by spaces.
# Example: |<mapZone other="Alaskan Standard Time" territory="US" type="America/Anchorage America/Juneau America/Nome America/Sitka America/Yakutat"/>
$mappings2 = $mappings1 | %{
    $mapping = $_
    $_.Type.Split(" ") | %{
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{type = $_; other = $mapping.other}
    }  
}

# Remove dup's
$mappings3 = $mappings2 | sort type -Unique

# Generate the case statements.
$mappings3 | %{ [String]::Format("`"{1}`" {{`"{0}`"}}", $_.Type, $_.Other)}

I need the switch to return only one entry so I pruned that list down. Here's the lookup script:
$CurrentTimeZone = Get-TimeZone

$tz = Switch -Wildcard ($CurrentTimeZone.id)
{ 
  "Afghanistan Standard Time"       { "Asia/Kabul" }
  "Alaskan Standard Time"           { "America/Anchorage" }
  "Aleutian Standard Time"          { "America/Adak" }
  "Altai Standard Time"             { "Asia/Barnaul" }
  "Arab Standard Time"              { "Asia/Bahrain" }
  "Arabian Standard Time"           { "Asia/Dubai" }
  "Arabic Standard Time"            { "Asia/Baghdad" }
  "Argentina Standard Time"         { "America/Buenos_Aires" }
  "Astrakhan Standard Time"         { "Europe/Astrakhan" }
  "Atlantic Standard Time"          { "America/Halifax" }
  "Atlantic Standard Time"          { "Atlantic/Bermuda" }
  "AUS Central Standard Time"       { "Australia/Darwin" }
  "Aus Central W. Standard Time"    { "Australia/Eucla" }
  "AUS Eastern Standard Time"       { "Australia/Sydney" }
  "Azerbaijan Standard Time"        { "Asia/Baku" }
  "Azores Standard Time"            { "Atlantic/Azores" }
  "Bahia Standard Time"             { "America/Bahia" }
  "Bangladesh Standard Time"        { "Asia/Dhaka" }
  "Belarus Standard Time"           { "Europe/Minsk" }
  "Bougainville Standard Time"      { "Pacific/Bougainville" }
  "Canada Central Standard Time"    { "America/Regina" }
  "Cape Verde Standard Time"        { "Atlantic/Cape_Verde" }
  "Caucasus Standard Time"          { "Asia/Yerevan" }
  "Cen. Australia Standard Time"    { "Australia/Adelaide" }
  "Central America Standard Time"   { "America/Costa_Rica" }
  "Central Asia Standard Time"      { "Asia/Bishkek" }
  "Central Brazilian Standard Time" { "America/Cuiaba" }
  "Central Europe Standard Time"    { "Europe/Prague" }
  "Central European Standard Time"  { "Europe/Warsaw" }
  "Central Pacific Standard Time"   { "Pacific/Guadalcanal" }
  "Central Standard Time (Mexico)"  { "America/Mexico_City" }
  "Central Standard Time"           { "America/Chicago" }
  "Chatham Islands Standard Time"   { "Pacific/Chatham" }
  "China Standard Time"             { "Asia/Hong_Kong" }
  "Cuba Standard Time"              { "America/Havana" }
  "Dateline Standard Time"          { "Etc/GMT+12" }
  "E. Africa Standard Time"         { "Africa/Nairobi" }
  "E. Australia Standard Time"      { "Australia/Brisbane" }
  "E. Europe Standard Time"         { "Europe/Chisinau" }
  "E. South America Standard Time"  { "America/Sao_Paulo" }
  "Easter Island Standard Time"     { "Pacific/Easter" }
  "Eastern Standard Time (Mexico)"  { "America/Cancun" }
  "Eastern Standard Time"           { "America/New_York" }
  "Egypt Standard Time"             { "Africa/Cairo" }
  "Ekaterinburg Standard Time"      { "Asia/Yekaterinburg" }
  "Fiji Standard Time"              { "Pacific/Fiji" }
  "FLE Standard Time"               { "Europe/Helsinki" }
  "Georgian Standard Time"          { "Asia/Tbilisi" }
  "GMT Standard Time"               { "Europe/London" }
  "Greenland Standard Time"         { "America/Godthab" }
  "Greenwich Standard Time"         { "Atlantic/Reykjavik" }
  "GTB Standard Time"               { "Europe/Athens" }
  "Haiti Standard Time"             { "America/Port-au-Prince" }
  "Hawaiian Standard Time"          { "Pacific/Honolulu" }
  "India Standard Time"             { "Asia/Calcutta" }
  "Iran Standard Time"              { "Asia/Tehran" }
  "Israel Standard Time"            { "Asia/Jerusalem" }
  "Jordan Standard Time"            { "Asia/Amman" }
  "Kaliningrad Standard Time"       { "Europe/Kaliningrad" }
  "Korea Standard Time"             { "Asia/Seoul" }
  "Libya Standard Time"             { "Africa/Tripoli" }
  "Line Islands Standard Time"      { "Pacific/Kiritimati" }
  "Lord Howe Standard Time"         { "Australia/Lord_Howe" }
  "Magadan Standard Time"           { "Asia/Magadan" }
  "Magallanes Standard Time"        { "America/Punta_Arenas" }
  "Marquesas Standard Time"         { "Pacific/Marquesas" }
  "Mauritius Standard Time"         { "Indian/Mauritius" }
  "Middle East Standard Time"       { "Asia/Beirut" }
  "Montevideo Standard Time"        { "America/Montevideo" }
  "Morocco Standard Time"           { "Africa/Casablanca" }
  "Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)" { "America/Mazatlan" }
  "Mountain Standard Time"          { "America/Denver" }
  "Myanmar Standard Time"           { "Asia/Rangoon" }
  "N. Central Asia Standard Time"   { "Asia/Novosibirsk" }
  "Namibia Standard Time"           { "Africa/Windhoek" }
  "Nepal Standard Time"             { "Asia/Katmandu" }
  "New Zealand Standard Time"       { "Pacific/Auckland" }
  "Newfoundland Standard Time"      { "America/St_Johns" }
  "Norfolk Standard Time"           { "Pacific/Norfolk" }
  "North Asia East Standard Time"   { "Asia/Irkutsk" }
  "North Asia Standard Time"        { "Asia/Krasnoyarsk" }
  "North Korea Standard Time"       { "Asia/Pyongyang" }
  "Omsk Standard Time"              { "Asia/Omsk" }
  "Pacific SA Standard Time"        { "America/Santiago" }
  "Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)"  { "America/Tijuana" }
  "Pacific Standard Time"           { "America/Los_Angeles" }
  "Pakistan Standard Time"          { "Asia/Karachi" }
  "Paraguay Standard Time"          { "America/Asuncion" }
  "Qyzylorda Standard Time"         { "Asia/Qyzylorda" }
  "Romance Standard Time"           { "Europe/Brussels" }
  "Russia Time Zone 10"             { "Asia/Srednekolymsk" }
  "Russia Time Zone 11"             { "Asia/Anadyr" }
  "Russia Time Zone 3"              { "Europe/Samara" }
  "Russian Standard Time"           { "Europe/Moscow" }
  "SA Eastern Standard Time"        { "America/Recife" }
  "SA Pacific Standard Time"        { "America/Bogota" }
  "SA Western Standard Time"        { "America/Puerto_Rico" }
  "Saint Pierre Standard Time"      { "America/Miquelon" }
  "Sakhalin Standard Time"          { "Asia/Sakhalin" }
  "Samoa Standard Time"             { "Pacific/Apia" }
  "Sao Tome Standard Time"          { "Africa/Sao_Tome" }
  "Saratov Standard Time"           { "Europe/Saratov" }
  "SE Asia Standard Time"           { "Asia/Bangkok" }
  "Singapore Standard Time"         { "Asia/Singapore" }
  "South Africa Standard Time"      { "Africa/Johannesburg" }
  "South Sudan Standard Time"       { "Africa/Juba" }
  "Sri Lanka Standard Time"         { "Asia/Colombo" }
  "Sudan Standard Time"             { "Africa/Khartoum" }
  "Syria Standard Time"             { "Asia/Damascus" }
  "Taipei Standard Time"            { "Asia/Taipei" }
  "Tasmania Standard Time"          { "Australia/Hobart" }
  "Tocantins Standard Time"         { "America/Araguaina" }
  "Tokyo Standard Time"             { "Asia/Tokyo" }
  "Tomsk Standard Time"             { "Asia/Tomsk" }
  "Tonga Standard Time"             { "Pacific/Tongatapu" }
  "Transbaikal Standard Time"       { "Asia/Chita" }
  "Turkey Standard Time"            { "Europe/Istanbul" }
  "Turks And Caicos Standard Time"  { "America/Grand_Turk" }
  "Ulaanbaatar Standard Time"       { "Asia/Ulaanbaatar" }
  "US Eastern Standard Time"        { "America/Indianapolis" }
  "US Mountain Standard Time"       { "America/Phoenix" }
  "UTC"                             { "Etc/UTC" }
  "UTC+12"                          { "Pacific/Funafuti" }
  "UTC+13"                          { "Pacific/Enderbury" }
  "UTC-02"                          { "Atlantic/South_Georgia" }
  "UTC-08"                          { "Pacific/Pitcairn" }
  "UTC-09"                          { "Pacific/Gambier" }
  "UTC-11"                          { "Pacific/Midway" }
  "Venezuela Standard Time"         { "America/Caracas" }
  "Vladivostok Standard Time"       { "Asia/Vladivostok" }
  "Volgograd Standard Time"         { "Europe/Volgograd" }
  "W. Australia Standard Time"      { "Australia/Perth" }
  "W. Central Africa Standard Time" { "Africa/Algiers" }
  "W. Europe Standard Time"         { "Europe/Berlin" }
  "W. Mongolia Standard Time"       { "Asia/Hovd" }
  "West Asia Standard Time"         { "Asia/Almaty" }
  "West Bank Standard Time"         { "Asia/Hebron" }
  "West Pacific Standard Time"      { "Pacific/Guam" }
  "Yakutsk Standard Time"           { "Asia/Yakutsk" }
  "Yukon Standard Time"             { "America/Whitehorse" }
}

write-host $CurrentTimeZone
write-host $tz


If you're happy to use my Noda Time package, it's relatively straightforward via TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.WindowsToTzdbIds

Note that you're not actually asking a question here - you appear to be trying to provide an answer, in a question...

Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! This is a Q&A site, meaning you're expected to format your initial post as a self-contained question. If you want to answer your own question, use the "Your Answer" box below. Please update your post so that it presents the question you want to ask (eg. "How do I translate Windows TZ names to cognate IANA identifiers") along with relevant background, context, and unsuccessful attempts at answering it - then post the solution as a separate answer below.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can simplify your code significantly by using XPath to lookup mappings directly against the XML document:
$xPath = '//supplementalData/windowsZones/mapTimezones/mapZone[@other = "Bahia Standard Time"]'
$bahiaEntry = $xml.SelectSingleNode($xPath)
$bahiaEntry.Type   # resolves to `America/Bahia`

Wrapping this in a function is trivial, but you may want to additionally host the function in a module, like so:
New-Module -Name tzResolutionModule -ScriptBlock {
  function Resolve-WindowsTimeZoneId {
    param(
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
      [Alias('Id')]
      [string]$TZIdentifier = $(Get-TimeZone |% Id))

    process {
      $xPathExpression = '//supplementalData/windowsZones/mapTimezones/mapZone[@other = "{0}"]' -f $TZIdentifier
      $mapZoneEntry = $script:_timeZoneMap.SelectSingleNode($xPathExpression)

      if (-not $mapZoneEntry){
        throw "Unable to resolve time zone label '${TZIdentifier}'"
      }
      else {
        # we found at least one entry, output the first corresponding IANA identifier
        return -split $mapZoneEntry.Type |Select-Object -First 1
      }
    }
  }

  $_timeZoneMap = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/raw/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml
} |Import-Module -Force

Wrapping the Resolve-WindowsTimeZoneId in a module allows us to take advantage of module-scoped variables for persistent storage - in this case to ensure we only download the zone mapping document once, on module import.
Now you can do:
PS ~> Resolve-WindowsTimeZoneId 'Central Standard Time'
America/Chicago

And get a near-instant response - but thanks to the [Parameter(...)] and [Alias(...)] decorators on the function parameter, you can now also do:
Get-TimeZone |Resolve-WindowsTimeZoneId
# or
'Central Standard Time' |Resolve-WindowsTimeZoneId


Wow, this is great, thank you! That really is a cleaner method for this. However, I have a couple of weird requirements... I can't have any external files and have to avoid using an external URL as some of the boxes my script will run on are really locked down. That's why I'm having to use a giant switch statement to get the job done. But your method is fab and I'm definitely going to use that in some other stuff I am working on. Thanks again!

@LuisEsteves You can embed the XML document contents in your script (or alongside it) if you want to solve it offline :)

Thanks Mathias! I got it to work with embedded XML. This version is going to work great for what I need. No more need to build a switch statement. I can just copy/paste the XML right into the script! Thank you again for the help! :)
